# Server 2012 R2 Sitelinks Best Practices

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I am having trouble understanding exactly how to properly configure AD Sites and Services overall. I can find countless articles how to technically configure it, but I can't seem to find any article that really goes into detail into what exactly it should look like.

**What I do know:**

- Every remote location (remote site) should have its full subnet listed in the subnets folder in Sites and Services
- Every location that has a domain controller should have its own "site".

**My Network**
I have the primary network in in the united states. I have two other "main" locations, 1 in Europe, and 1 in Asia. Each "main" site has at least 2 domain controllers for redundancy. Spread throughout the world I have about 25 small remote office sites with no servers, just small buildings with groups less than 25 active users at any given time.

**What I *think* I know**

- Subnets should only be listed once, specifically under the "main" site they have the best connection to.
- I should have 3 main site links as follows. (US-Asia,US-Europe,Asia-Europe)
- I have no idea how to configure NTDS replication optimally.

Answer (score 2):

A book could be written in answer to this question. That being said, I'll make a few comments:

1. You're correct in that your subnets should be created and associated with the appropriate site in AD Sites and Services.
2. You don't really need the Asia-Europe site link. Creating only the US-Europe and the US-Asia site links is enough to ensure a complete replication topology. This is effectively a hub and spoke design with the US site being the hub. This is a fairly common design.
3. You don't have to and in most cases shouldn't try to manually create the replication topology. Create your sites, your site links, and your subnets and let the KCC and ISTG create the replication topology for you. You and I are not smarter than the KCC and the ISTG and in the majority of scenarios we should leave them to do the job they were designed to do and not interfere with that. The role of the KCC and the ISTG is to create a least cost, loop free replication topology and it is well designed to do just that.

Comment: Questions that are too broad should be closed, not answered.

Comment: Ok, sounds like I was on the right track. As far as only have 2 sitelinks, I figured it would be I tuitive to have the 3rd sitelinks in case the US hub for some reason went down or was otherwise unreachable at least the europe Asia would still replicate changes to each other instead of waiting for the US core site to come back up.

Comment: Sure. That's a good reason to have the Europe-Asia site link.